# Other than changing the return type, how else can i fix this?

Tags: sql

I know I can change the return type of the tripNumb function, but are there any other ways?td::endl; // should print 30
   return 0;
 }

Comment: Surely your book broaches this subject?? This is "how to use functions".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the function to take a *reference*, note the `&`:

```
void tripleNumber(int& x) {
    x = 3 * x;
}
```

`x` in the function then refers to `x` in the caller, rather than a copy being taken.

Comment: Also, a pointer `int *x` works too. Some people prefer this way to make it clear `x` will be modified in the function.

Comment: @dave: I too am of that ilk although it's an old-fashioned view, so I'm told.

Comment: Sure, it's debatable. References eliminate the need to check for `nullptr` for example. Just noting it here since many people still do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `pointer` like shown below to handle the case. First pass the address of x from main function to function `tripleNumber()` and store it in a pointer `(int* x)` then dereference `x` like `(*x)` to access it value and modify it.

```
 #include <iostream>
 void tripleNumber(int*x) {
   *x = 3*(*x);
 }

 int main() {
   int x = 10;
   std::cout <<x<<std::endl; // should print 10
   tripleNumber(&x);
   std::cout <<(x)<<std::endl; // should print 30
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: With pointer, you theoretically have to handle `nullptr` contrary to reference.